# Does an Android package availability checking service exist?

Tags: android, conflict, google-play, package-name

I am new to developing android and I would like to confirm that the **package name** that I have picked **does not conflict with any existing packages** on the play store or other major apk markets.
**Does such a service or website exist?!**
Ideally I am expecting a website that functions similar to Gmail's email ID checking system.

*In other words how to check whether a package name that I have picked is available?*

**Note:**

- I do not yet have a Google play publisher account

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I am new to developing android and I would like to confirm that the package name that I have picked does not conflict with any existing packages on the play store or other major apk markets.

If you follow the recommendations, and choose a package name based off of your domain name, you should not run into any conflicts.

> Does such a service or website exist?!

To check whether your package name is in use on the Play Store, use the Play Store, with a URL of `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=your.package.name.goes.here`.

You will need to contact the other "major apk markets" to see if they offer a similar facility. Bear in mind that asking on StackOverflow for off-site resources like this is off-topic.

> Ideally I am expecting a website that functions similar to Gmail's email ID checking system.

Since a search for `"email ID checking system" gmail` on a major search engine turns up zero matches, I do not know what you mean by "Gmail's email ID checking system".

Comment: By Gmail's email ID checking system I basically just meant how, Gmail signup shows a live update of whether the email address put into the field is available or not.

Answer (score -1):

i dont think so there is any website that will tell that your package name is unique or not !

but if by chance your package name is similar to any other app ! 
 you can easily change your package name by

Right click on your Android Project>> click on android tool >> then choose Rename Package 
thats the easiest way to change package name :)